# Micronaut application yml placeholder with default value not working

Tags: micronaut

Micronaut application yml placeholder with default value nor working when value is having ":" in it

Application.yml

```
report:
   url: ${REPORT_HOST:"http://localhost:8080/"}
```

Error

> Failed to inject value for parameter url
>   Unable to convert value [8080/"] to travel type URI due to illegal character in path at index 5: 8080/

I tried with and without double quotes for value

Micronaut version : 1.0.4

Answer (score 5):

You need to use back ticks. This is documented here https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#propertySource

Answer (score 1):

Change:

`report: url: ${REPORT_HOST:"http://localhost:8080/"}`

to:

`` report: url: ${REPORT_HOST:`http://localhost:8080/`} ``

Micronaut version 3.1.0